# Why am I unable to navigate into a new window with the Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, window-handles

I am unable to navigate into a new window, as it is showing the same window for both parent and child. I use this code. What is the problem?

```
String parent_Window = driver.getWindowHandle();
Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
 for(String window_Handle  : handles){
    if(!window_Handle.equals(parent_Window)){
        driver.switchTo().window(window_Handle);
        //<!--Perform operation here for new window--> 

     driver.switchTo().window(parent_Window);
        }
    }
```

Comment: is size of handles is two means it collected two windowhandles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the below code:

```
// Store the current window handle
String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

 // Switch to new window opened
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){
driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
 }

// Perform the actions on new window

// Close the new window, if that window no more required
driver.close();

 // Switch back to original browser (first window)
driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably, you tried to switch before opening a new window. If this is the case, get the main window handle first then try opening a new window and switch to your new window(or tab).

I hope it will help.